# Interger print in Linux Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, printing

```
section .text

global _start

_start:

        mov eax, 4
        mov ebx, 1
        mov edx, num
        int 0x80
        mov eax, 1
        mov ebx, 0
        int 0x80

section .data

        num db 5
```

~

It compiles well, but prints nothing. Who can tell me what`s wrong?

Comment: You need to convert the number 5 into the numeral "5". See for yourself: replace `num db 5` with `num db "5"`. Of course, the general approach requires an `itoa` equivalent. SO Doc has something on that.

Comment: I have to wtite just like this? num db "5" ?

Comment: Try and see what happen :) Take a look at an ASCII table, though ASCII is probably not the charset used by your terminal, the first 127 chars are all the same in all western charsets. Remember: you write strings not numbers.

Comment: I have almost tried it. But still print nothing. Please can you write the right code, because I don`t really understand you. Thanks.

Comment: Consult a syscall table for the correct use of registers :)

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `sys_write` properly. The string address [should go into `ecx`, and the number of bytes to write should go into `edx`](http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/):

```
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1    ; fd (stdout)
    mov ecx, num  ; const char*
    mov edx, 1    ; count
    int 0x80
```

Comment: You should also mention that, in order for this code to work, David must do as Margaret advised him in the comments and change `num` to be a string, rather than an integer.